# Redirection in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on custom module. I try to redirect my module to magento catalog category page. The link for the page is

http://localhost/project/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/cc65595b0383ca64fb245cb7de2359d8/

I have tried following methods without success.

`$this->_redirect($this->getUrl("admin/catalog_category/"));`
`$this->_redirect("admin/catalog_category/");`

Magento is removing admin from url ? final url look like that

http://localhost/project/index.php//catalog_category/index/key/cc65595b0383ca64fb245cb7de2359d8/

I didn't figure out why admin is skipping from my url ? can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$this->_redirect("adminhtml/catalog_category");
```

The first URI(ie adminhtml) is module name and for admin area the module name is adminhtml.